# Can we customize Spring Batch meta tables?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

can we be able to change the names of these tables?

```
  Default Table Name->Customize Name
 -----------------------------------------
• BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE->JobInstanceDescription
• BATCH_JOB_PARAMS-> JobExecutionParameters
• BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION[Customized Name Will Be Provided In Similar Fashion]
• BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT->[Customized Name Will Be Provided In Similar Fashion]
• BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION->[Customized Name Will Be Provided In Similar Fashion]
• BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION_CONTEXT->[Customized Name Will Be Provided In Similar Fashion]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37436658/spring-batch-table-prefix-when-using-java-config

Comment: @StanislavL : I guess, prefix would only change table name prefix but having prefix property retains suffix part too like - `GFA.BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE` so `JOB_INSTANCE`  etc will be appended to that prefix. What OP is looking for is full table name change without these suffixes. I will explore but as far I know, that wouldn't be possible.

Comment: @StanislavL I have checked that before asking the question.As Sabir Khan mentioned only prefix part can be changed but changing suffix is not known.Also i have  checked documentation for Spring batch 3.0.0 but it seems that part is not documented.May be I have to custom build Spring batch framework for my use case by changing source code and schema files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Its not possible to fully rename a Spring Batch meta data table. Only prefix part can be changed.

My answer is based on the fact that I looked at codes of few classes in Spring Batch API like - `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcExecutionContextDao` & `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao`

and these classes are using hard coded queries like -

`private static final String CREATE_JOB_INSTANCE = "INSERT into %PREFIX%JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)"
            + " values (?, ?, ?, ?)";`

&

`private static final String FIND_JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT = "SELECT SHORT_CONTEXT, SERIALIZED_CONTEXT "
            + "FROM %PREFIX%JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT WHERE JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ?";`
 etc etc.

so suffix parts like `JOB_INSTANCE` & `JOB_EXECUTION_CONTEXT` are hard coded so it can't be changed.

Comment: My company policy is say that a table can not have name lenght more than 30 so it would be nice if we can change the metadata table names.